# Set parent of matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I have a problem with setting the figure generated by the following code. It does not close when the mainwindow is closed. I have used `self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteonClose)` in the mainwindow. The mainwindow object is passed as parent while calling the `smd` function. Even though, I have explicitly set the parent of canvas, Figure generated is not closed when mainwindow is closed.

```
def smd(self,parent):

    from pylab import *
    import matplotlib

    from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

    from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QTAgg as NavigationToolbar

    from matplotlib.figure import Figure
    import pylab as p

    sm = [1,2,3]
    fig = p.figure()

    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.bar(range(len(sm)),sm,align='center')
    ax.set_xticks(range(len(sm)))

    canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    canvas.setParent(parent)
    #p.setParent(self)
    canvas.draw()
    fig.setParent(parent)
    print "parent is ", parent, canvas.parent()

    p.show()
```

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "Figure generated is not closed when mainwindow is closed". What exactly is the example supposed to be showing us?

Comment: The above snippet appears in a QMainWindow class. When I run the program, and call this smd function by using a push button, the figure appears. But, when I close the mainwindow of the program, the figure still remains shown. But, what I expect is the figure also to be closed, as it is a child widget of the main program.

Comment: Ok thanks. Perhaps you could fix the indentation of the code?